# jQuery combobox with nested option values?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm trying to create a combobox with a set of nested option values, using flyouts for the sub-values.

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

seems to be the way to go for a flat list of options, but how can I use it with nested options?

If there's a better plugin to use, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this plugin actually renders a select tag on the page, which itself does not support nesting, only optgroups. If you want nested elements inside of the combobox, you would have to use another plugin or component.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Any suggestions for which plugin to use for this? I have looked quite a bit, but I haven't found anything that fits the bill.